How to use Kibana export API?
I am using Kibana export API to get the rule in dev tools, but it's throwing error.
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Trying to export object(s) with non-exportable types: rule:5f598262-6916-46fc-ae83-4e9acf0f5554"
}

I have tried below API
POST kbn:api/saved_objects/_export
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "5f598262-6916-46fc-ae83-4e9acf0f5554",
      "type": "rule"
    }
  ],
  "excludeExportDetails": true,
  "includeReferencesDeep": false
}

